# NLog Replace Layout Renderer not work with json content

Tags: c#, json, regex, nlog

I use a third party package that depending on Nlog 4.7 and NLog.AspNetCore 4.8, and the package will write log.

In my Nlog.config

```
<logger name="package namespace" level="Info" writeTo="packageFile" />
<target xsi:type="File" name="packageFile" fileName="${baseFilePath}/packageFile.log" KeepFileOpen="true" layout="${message}" concurrentWrites="true" />
```

It's work, but now I need replace content in message. I find [Replace Layout Renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Replace-Layout-Renderer) that is I need.

The message is json string like this:

```
{"ABC":{"DEF":"AA00014325","GHI":"01"}}
```

I want to replace message become

```
{"ABC":{"DEF":"A****14325","GHI":"01"}}
```

This is the pattern I have used: [A-Z]\d{1}\d{2}
I used this to test it against: https://regex101.com/

Update:
I also try the pattern by [.NET Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

My Nlog.config like this:

```
<variable name ="messageReplace" value="${replace:inner=${message}:searchFor=[A-Z]\\d{1\}\\d{2\}:replaceWith=****:regex=true}" />
<logger name="package namespace" level="Info" writeTo="packageFile" />
<target xsi:type="File" name="packageFile" fileName="${baseFilePath}/packageFile.log" KeepFileOpen="true" layout="${messageReplace}" concurrentWrites="true" />
```

But it's not work......

I change my Nlog.config like this:

```
<variable name ="message1" value="AA00014325" />
<variable name ="messageReplace" value="${replace:inner=${message1}:searchFor=[A-Z]\\d{1\}\\d{2\}:replaceWith=****:regex=true}" />
<logger name="package namespace" level="Info" writeTo="packageFile" />
<target xsi:type="File" name="packageFile" fileName="${baseFilePath}/packageFile.log" KeepFileOpen="true" layout="${messageReplace}" concurrentWrites="true" />
```

It's working...but if change message1 to

```
"AA00014325"
```

It not working again....Why?

I want to replace json string in message, how can I do?

Information:

- Platform : ASP.NET Core 3
- Nlog version : 4.7
- NLog.AspNetCore version : 4.8

Thank you!

Comment: The regex doesn't seem to be matching from my side, double checked with http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: @DaneBalia I try the regex [A-Z]\d{1}\d{2} is OK on  .NET Regex Tester

Answer (score 1):

So using this configuration, I got it to work as per screenshot.
Somethings to bear in mind is that the configuration is XML so to [escape correctly](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#content-escaping). But I see you got that right ✔. So I believe its down to your regex.

```
 <variable name="messageNoDigits" value="${replace:inner=${message}:searchFor=[A-Z]\\d\{3\}:replaceWith=****:regex=true}" />
```

[image]